# Unexpected result for select uuid()

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Running OrientDB 2.2, if I simply execute "select uuid()" in Studio, the result I get is:    `rO0ABXNyAA5qYXZhLnV0aWwuVVVJRLyZA/eYbYUvAgACSgAMbGVhc3RTaWdCaXRzSgALbW9zdFNpZ0JpdHN4cLRqgrnPruY1cNh/pBZ9Q/Q=`

What is this and how do I get a conventional UUID?

Comment: By the way, if I use the uuid() function as part of an insert or update statement (i.e. to write the uuid() result to a record property), it works as expected (i.e. the record property contains a UUID).

Comment: It appears to be returning a Base64 encoding of the value.  I've opened an issue against 2.2.x.  Thanks!

Comment: @Colin: I thought that too, but it's too long. So I decoded it, and this is what it's encoding: `srjava.util.UUIDm/JleastSigBitsJmostSigBitsxpj5p}C`

Comment: Hi @eric.  It is Base64 representation, but it's actually the Java serialization of a UUID.  It's not my favorite, but you can at least use this to get a string value: insert into MyClass set uuid = format("%s",uuid())

Answer (score 0):

The `UUID` is an automatic generated id. Generates a `UUID` as a 128-bits values string. For more information look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Yes, I'm very familiar with UUIDs (128-bit binary values generally expressed as xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). My question is about why OrientDB Studio doesn't return a UUID if I just SELECT UUID(), but it does write a valid UUID to the database when I use the UUID() function on a insert or update. This isn't a critical issue, I'm really just curious what the long alpha-numeric string is (that obviously isn't a UUID in any form that I'm aware of).